# Panning on a hyperlink triggers the hyperlink on mouse up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use jQuery.click to handle the mouse click event on an image but panning on a hyperlink triggers the hyperlink on mouse up. I tried to disable click in pan zoom event by checking if the mouse is dragging:

```
var element = document.getElementById('advanced-zoom');
var flag = 0;

element.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    flag = 0;
}, false);

element.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
    flag = 1;
}, false);...
```

but without success in my case. Is there a method I can call to check if a pan is active and prevent a mouse click event on pan? Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ogdan/a352gLvy/50/